# Windows 7 slowly freezing (app by app)

Tags: windows-7, freeze, pgp, displaylink

I think this is different from other "win 7 freeze" questions. :) I consider myself pretty experienced user but this is just too much for me. Let me explain what happens:

1. Some program freezes randomly
2. I try to open task manager but it won't open (hitting ctrl+alt+del -> task manager won't work either)
3. **I can't even win+r calc or notepad!**
4. Other open programs run just fine (I can open new tabs to chrome and surf on the web and use remote desktop etc)
5. Star menu is working fast but I still can't open anything (and context menus on desktop are working)
6. Slowly other programs start to freeze also
7. Finally I'm tired to situation and I hit the power switch to restart

Please, tell me where I should start to tracing this problem? What log files should I check?

And one more thing. I got some problems with display drivers. I randomly got bluescreens if I use Aero but now I'm not using it.

Edit: **I usually put my computer to sleep between days and I think this problem applies only after few days...**

**I also need to mention that when it freezes the HD (SSD) light is constantly illuminated although nothing happens.**

My hardware:

- Dell Latitude E6530 laptop
- i7-3740QM
- RAM 16 GB
- **ADATA SX900 512 SSD**
- NVIDIA NVS 5200M
- Extra display on vga
- Lenovo USB 2.0 Dock with extra display (DisplayLink)
- Plantronics headset on USB

My software:

- Win 7 Enterprise
- Office 2013
- Microsoft Office Communicator
- **PGP Desktop** <- I suspect this
- McAfee agent
- Google Chrome
- Sometimes HP Application Lifecycle Management on Internet Explorer 10 (elevated mode)

**Response to the comments:**

Thanks for your comments!

- Haven't checked the ram failure yet. Any suggestions how to do that?
- Disabling McAfee is not possible because it is centrally managed.
- About the CPU usage. I can hear that from processor fan if something is hogging resources. Sometimes HP ALM does that but I think that is not the source of the problem.
- I need to disconnect the Lenovo USB dock and hook up my other display with HDMI. I will let you know if that helps.
- Only thing worth mentioning in event log was one warning: Source: Search / Task Category: Gatherer `The protocol host process 5840 did not respond and is being forcibly terminated {filter host process 8732}.`

Comment: have you checked for a RAM failure? Also, see if disabling mcAfee helps.

Comment: It could help if you monitored your CPU usage (with Task Manager or Process Explorer) and found certain processes hogging the computer's resources. It could also be a graphics problem, in which the underlying system is trying to contact the graphics but it isn't answering as it should. It would look like the computer is freezing when it is just waiting for a graphics answer. Try to disconnect the extra display. The graphics might have a bigger workload.

Comment: Looks to me like all processes requiring I/O are freezing (as they cannot read from hard disk). This could be because of Symantec PGP, it also could be McAfee (maybe the two together). It could also be your hardware (especially regarding your aero blue screens). Have a look at the [event log](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_Viewer).

Comment: I will add responses directly as edits to the post.

Comment: My comments on your updated info: RAM failure can be tested with [Memtest86](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memtest86). Try to use an application I mentioned to check the process; just hearing the fan work doesn't tell anything about what process is hogging all resources. Without knowing what name that process corresponds it doesn't mean anything; some stuff like that happens on a regular basis. You did mentioned that McAfee is centrally managed so I assume you can ultimately ask someone to turn it off temporarily at where you work.

Comment: Given your McAfee is centrally managed, I'm assuming this PC is part of a corporate network, in which case I would highly recommend you speak to your IT department to get this issue resolved.